# Nested IF function for OR logic

Tags: powerbi, dax

I cannot seem to see what I am doing wrong with the following nested IF formula...

internet search

```
IF (
    SEARCH (
        "compontentdissociation",
        'njrew_k_prmry_bicon_outcm'[INDREV_SUMMARYREVISIONREASONS],
        1,
        1000
    ) <> 1000,
    18,
    IF (
        SEARCH (
            "dislocation subluxation",
            'njrew_k_prmry_bicon_outcm'[INDREV_SUMMARYREVISIONREASONS],
            1,
            1000
        ) <> 1000,
        18,
        IF (
            SEARCH (
                "Prosthesis Dislocation",
                'njrew_k_prmry_bicon_outcm'[INDREV_SUMMARYREVISIONREASONS],
                1,
                1000
            ) <> 1000,
            18
        )
    )
)
```

the ability to use or with 3 conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the OR operator `||` like this and you don't need nesting:

```
IF (
    SEARCH (
        "compontentdissociation",
        'njrew_k_prmry_bicon_outcm'[INDREV_SUMMARYREVISIONREASONS],
        1,
        1000
    ) <> 1000
        || SEARCH (
            "dislocation subluxation",
            'njrew_k_prmry_bicon_outcm'[INDREV_SUMMARYREVISIONREASONS],
            1,
            1000
        ) <> 1000
        || SEARCH (
            "Prosthesis Dislocation",
            'njrew_k_prmry_bicon_outcm'[INDREV_SUMMARYREVISIONREASONS],
            1,
            1000
        ) <> 1000,
    18
)
```

You could also use a `SWITCH` function to avoid nesting:

```
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    SEARCH (
        "compontentdissociation",
        'njrew_k_prmry_bicon_outcm'[INDREV_SUMMARYREVISIONREASONS],
        1,
        1000
    ) <> 1000, 18,
    SEARCH (
        "dislocation subluxation",
        'njrew_k_prmry_bicon_outcm'[INDREV_SUMMARYREVISIONREASONS],
        1,
        1000
    ) <> 1000, 18,
    SEARCH (
        "Prosthesis Dislocation",
        'njrew_k_prmry_bicon_outcm'[INDREV_SUMMARYREVISIONREASONS],
        1,
        1000
    ) <> 1000, 18
)
```

Comment: Alexis. many thanks for the helpful feedback on the question.